# Friend Class Function For Another Class?

Tags: c++

I'm trying to program a Texas Hold'em game in C++ as practice. I've just started reading about friend functions, and thought about using them to allow players to draw cards from the deck.

I have currently defined two classes as follows:

```
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <stdio.h>
typedef unsigned int uint;    

class deck

{
private:
    std::vector<card> cards;
public:
    void initialize(void)
    {
        char suits[] = { 'H', 'C', 'D', 'S' };
        uint values[] = { 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14 };
        for (uint i = 0; i != 4; i++)
        {
            for (uint j = 0; j != 13; j++)
            {
                cards.push_back(card(suits[i], values[j]));
            }
        }
    }
    void shuffle(void)
    {
        uint i = cards.size(), random_index;
        card shuffled_card;
        while (i > 0)
        {
            random_index = rand() % (i + 1);
            shuffled_card = cards[random_index];
            cards[random_index] = cards[i];
            cards[i] = shuffled_card;
            i--;
        }
    }
};

class player
{
private:
    std::string name;
    uint chips;
    std::vector<card> hand;
public:
    player(std::string set_name, uint set_chips) { name = set_name; chips = set_chips; }
    void draw(deck& target_deck, uint number)
    {
        // Draw cards from the top of the 
        // target deck.
    }
};
```

I'd like the `draw()` method of the `player` class to take a reference to a member of the `deck` class, and to be able to remove `number` cards from `cards` of `deck`. Since `cards` is a private element of `deck`, I can't reference it in `draw()` as `target_deck.cards`. I've tried adding a friend function into the `deck` class:

```
friend void player::draw(deck&target_deck, uint number);
```

This, however, doesn't solve the problem. Is there something wrong with the code, or are the only solutions (a) defining a friend function outside of `player` or (b) making the entire `player` class a friend of `deck`?

Thanks in advance for any pointers!

Comment: The answer by Greg is good, i dont think Friend functions are what you should be using here

Comment: whats up with the `initialize` function instead of a constructor?

Comment: Friend member functions should work: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ahhw8bzz.aspx

Comment: `cards.size()` will be a `std::size_t` which may or may not be an `unsigned int`

Comment: Greg's answer is probably how you should implement this, but FWIW, the reason your friend declaration didn't work is because player::draw isn't declared yet. You need to do a bit of forward-declaration dance to do it in this case, but it's possible.

Comment: there are so many things I want to say about this http://pastebin.com/uq1eXXxd

Comment: @RyanHaining Definitely should've thought to use a constructor there--thanks. Appreciate the pastebin file also. This is a personal exercise while I work through Koenig and Moo's "Accelerated C++", so a lot of that syntax is new to me!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would solve this by providing a public function `deck::draw()`, which returns the top card from the deck (and removes it from the deck). Then you can implement `player::draw()` in terms of `deck::draw()` by calling it as many times as needed.

If you implement a `deck::draw()`, then you will probably want `deck::initialize()` to clear the deck before pushing 52 new cards onto it.

As a minor style note, the notation of putting `void` in the parameter list for a function that takes no arguments is supported in C++ for backwards compatibility with C, but is not commonly used in new C++ code. The reason C supports it is because a function declaration (prototype) `foo()` says nothing about the arguments the function takes, while `foo(void)` says that the function takes no arguments. C++ always treats `foo()` as taking no arguments.

Answer (score 0):

You have to put `player`'s definition before deck. And also try defining the `draw` function after defining `deck` class.

```
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <stdio.h>
typedef unsigned int uint;    

class deck;

class player
{
private:
    std::string name;
    uint chips;
    std::vector<card> hand;
public:
    player(std::string set_name, uint set_chips) { name = set_name; chips = set_chips; }
    void draw(deck& target_deck, uint number); // define it outside.

};


class deck    
{
private:
    std::vector<card> cards;
public:
    friend void draw(deck& target_deck, uint number);
    void initialize(void)
    {
        char suits[] = { 'H', 'C', 'D', 'S' };
        uint values[] = { 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14 };
        for (uint i = 0; i != 4; i++)
        {
            for (uint j = 0; j != 13; j++)
            {
                cards.push_back(card(suits[i], values[j]));
            }
        }
    }
    void shuffle(void)
    {
        uint i = cards.size(), random_index;
        card shuffled_card;
        while (i > 0)
        {
            random_index = rand() % (i + 1);
            shuffled_card = cards[random_index];
            cards[random_index] = cards[i];
            cards[i] = shuffled_card;
            i--;
        }
    }
};

 void player::draw(deck& target_deck, uint number)
 {
      // Draw cards from the top of the 
      // target deck.
 }
```